# Enable vendor prefix autocomplete in CSS files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, vendor-prefix

How can I tell VSCode to automatically add vendor prefixed style properties when adding a property without vendor prefixes added in CSS files (not SASS nor LESS files)?

Comment: There is an Autoprefixer plug-in for VS Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-autoprefixer

Answer (score 8):

I have been using **[VS Code Autoprefixer plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-autoprefixer)**. It supports CSS, SCSS and SASS.

Select all CSS, then hit command pallet, then hit `AutoPrefixer: Run`.

If nothing happens, then add this below section in `settings.json` for Autoprefixer -

```
"autoprefixer.options": {
    "browsers": [
        "last 4 versions",
        "ie >= 9",
        "> 5%"
    ]
}
```

After that select all CSS, then hit command pallet, then hit `AutoPrefixer: Run` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using **css-auto-prefix** plugin.
For most of the CSS3 properties it works fine.
Though still in beta version, improvements are going on.You should try this one, it saves time and energy.

Perform following steps to install css-auto-prefix plugin in vscode.

1. Open VS Code.
2. Click Ctrl+Shift+X(on windows) or click on extensions icon on the left most panel.
3. A search box will appear. Simply type **css-auto-prefix**.
4. Install and Reload and you are good to go.

[css-auto-prefix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOW2r.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can install "**Auto prefix**" or "**Css Auto Prefix**" Extension in your vs code but I am not quite sure if it would be ok to write our own ***snippest*** for the prefix maybe that way it will be more customizable.

But we also can always install `"auto prefix"` via **NPM** a *Node package manager*.

Answer (score 0):

**You Might want to read this before you want to use a Vendor Prefix plug-in/Extension through VScode.**

Official
Link:
https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

Text Editors and IDE
Autoprefixer should be used in assets build tools. Text editor plugins are not a good solution, because prefixes decrease code readability and you will need to change values in all prefixed properties.

I recommend you to learn how to use build tools like Parcel. They work much better and will open you a whole new world of useful plugins and automation.

If you can’t move to a build tool, you can use text editor plugins:

Visual Studio Code
Atom Editor
Sublime Text
Brackets

If you decide to take @Pinaki approach with is okay but won't be able to get all the updates necessary.