# How do I enable auto prefix in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, webkit, autoprefixer

I've been trying to make my website more responsive but I'm having trouble enabling auto prefixer in visual studio code. I installed the extension but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You shoud go to visual studio extensions.

1 - Install Autoprefixer.
[image: Autoprefixer extension]

2 - Ctrl + Shift + P > Type "Preferences: Open Settings(JSON)".
[image]

3 - Add this code snippet :
"autoprefixer.options": {
"browsers": [
"last 4 versions",
"ie >= 9",
"> 5%"
]
}
[image]

4- Restart Visual Studio Code.

5 - Select the css code you want to prefix.

6 - Ctrl + Shift + P > Type "Autoprefixer: Run".
[image]

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to setting and search for auto prefixer in search bar at the top you will be able to enable and customize any extension. Moreover, you can check the detail of the extension to know how to use it, Or You check out this answer also [Enable vendor prefix autocomplete in CSS files in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928781/enable-vendor-prefix-autocomplete-in-css-files-in-visual-studio-code).